# IE8 alt / title tags in the images

Tags: image, title, alt

There is one client who cannot see the img title tags in IE8. Is there a setting to disable alt / title tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alt tags don't show as hover text in IE8 (correclty).

Use the title attribute instead